# What is PrimeFaces p:editor based on?

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces

I want to add some client-side functionality to the PrimeFaces **p:editor**, but for some reason I am not able to uncover what JavaScript client side code they used to build the component.  Could anyone point me to that?

P.S. two things I want to do is make the component resizable (PrimeFaces doesn't support that) and I want to add shortcut buttons to insert pre-programmed text.   Any hints about how this will done will be appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

PrimeFaces p:editor uses [CLEditor](http://premiumsoftware.net/cleditor/)

[look at this thread](http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15776)

also you should take a look at the [PrimeFaces Extensions Project](http://code.google.com/p/primefaces-extensions) they implemented an editor that uses the [CKEditor](http://ckeditor.com/)

Comment: thanks for the answer but the Primefaces forum link doesn't work.  Could you check it?

Comment: Strange... it works for me... hete it is again  http://forum.primefaces.org/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=15776

Comment: It works now -- I was getting an error message before perhaps PrimeFaces needs an upgrade. ;)

Answer (score 1):

`<p:editor/>` JavaScript source is located in `/META-INF/resources/primefaces/editor/editor.js` inside primefaces-xxx.jar.

Comment: Yes I did look at that but it is one long line stripped for production.  No clue as to where it comes from.

Comment: @AlanObject, paste this line into any JS editor, which is capable of "reformatting" the code. Personally I do it in Intellij IDEA