# How to add controls from the property file in PrimeFaces p:editor?

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I am developing a project in PrimeFaces.

I used [`<p:editor>`](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/input/editor.xhtml) in my project.

With that, I need editorConfiguration(controls) from the property File.

Here,I added the code(`configuration=""`) from RichFaces and I need same as this in PrimeFaces `<p:editor>`

**Richfaces code:**

**richPage.jsp**

```
<rich:editor id="contentEditor" value="....." configuration="#
       {ControlPanel.editorConfiguration}">
    <f:param name="save_onsavecallback" value="saveText"/>
</rich:editor>
```

**editorConfiguration.properties**

```
theme="advanced"
plugins="save,paste,searchreplace"
theme_advanced_buttons1="open,|,newdocument,|,save,|,cancel,|cut,|,copy,|,paste,|,pastetext,|,pasteword,|,undo,|,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,|,search,|,replace"
theme_advanced_toolbar_location="top"
theme_advanced_toolbar_align="left"
width="600"
height="400"
```

In this above code used `configuration="{ControlPanel.editorConfigurationPath}"` in RichFaces.

Is there any option instead of `configuration=""` in PrimeFaces for `<p:editor>`?

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to use the **same** property file.

RichFaces editor is based on TinyMCE ([reference](https://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/rich_editor.html)) while PrimeFaces editor uses CLEditor ([reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9957655/what-is-primefaces-peditor-based-on)). (As a side note, there is also `pe:ckEditor` in PrimeFaces Extension which, as you may guess, uses CKEditor.)

**However**, `p:editor` accepts to be configured thanks to the `controls=""` attribute.

You'll find all the available controls in the [PrimeFaces User Guide](http://www.primefaces.org/documentation) but I will report them here:

> **Custom Toolbar**
>
> Toolbar of editor is easy to customize using controls option;
>
> • bold
>   • italic
>   • underline
>   • strikethrough
>   • subscript
>   • superscript
>   • font
>   • size
>   • style
>   • color
>   • highlight
>   • bullets
>   • numbering
>   • alignleft
>   • center
>   • alignright
>   • justify
>   • undo
>   • redo
>   • rule
>   • image
>   • link
>   • unlink
>   • cut
>   • copy
>   • paste
>   • pastetext
>   • print
>   • source
>   • outdent
>   • indent
>   • removeFormat

Example:

```
<p:editor value="#{bean.text}" controls="bold italic underline strikethrough" />
```

Note: If you want to share your controls, you can also define your controls elsewhere (in a bean or in a property file) and use something like `controls="#{ControlPanel.editorConfiguration}"` or `controls="#{config['options']}"`